# Assign any IEnumerable to object property

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a list of objects created using reflection, they are all the same type, however the type is unknown at compile time.

I'm trying to figure out the *best* way of assigning this list (also using reflection) to an object property which could be **any** IEnumerable.

```
List<object>
ArrayList
Custom : List<object>
```

The only approach I have is to assume the property is an ICollection then loop through the IEnumerable and add each item. (See below, where `list` is the IEnumerable source, `key` is the string name of the object property and `result` is the object itself)

```
foreach (object item in list) {
    PropertyInfo prop = result.GetType().GetProperty(key);
    var collection = prop.GetValue(result, null);

    Type collectionType = collection.GetType();
    MethodInfo add = collectionType.GetMethod("Add", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    add.Invoke(collection, new object[] { item });
}
```

Comment: "however the type is unknown at runtime" - don't you mean "at compile-time"? the type is surely discoverable at runtime...?

Comment: Yes you're right, edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say the data is homogeous, I would suggest typing it as closely as you can; so assuming `list` is non-empty, `list[0].GetType()` will tell you the `Type` of all the data. At this point, you could do:

```
IList typedList = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(
           typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(itemType));
...
foreach(var item in list) typedListAdd(item);
```

or you could use an array:

```
Array arr = Array.CreateInstance(itemCount, list.Count);
list.CopyTo(arr, 0);
```

Either of which will give you a *well typed* list, which tends to work much better for most purposes (data-binding, serialization, or just reflection).

If `list` is not actually a *list*, but is just `IEnumerable`, then you can *basically* still do the same thing, but simply defer the creation until the first item:

```
IList typedList = null;
foreach(object item in list) {
    if(typedList == null) {
        typedList = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(
           typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(item.GetType()));
    }
    typedList.Add(item);
}
return typedList ?? new object[0];
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this solves the core problem. Populating IList<T> with the contents of the IEnumerable still wouldn't let me assign IList<T> to a property of type Custom : List<T> I could start with IList<T> instead of the IEnumerable if needed. The problem is getting that data into an IEnumerable property where the generic type is unknown or non-generic

Comment: @Rob2211 oh, you want to use the *property* type? sure : then *use the property type*: `IList list = (IList) (prop.GetValue(obj) ?? Activator.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType);` - and just `Add` to the list; note you might also want to `SetValue` if you created the list

Comment: That assumes that the property type implements or inherits from IList in some way. It just places a limitation on the data structures surrounding this system, that they should never define collection-like properties which aren't IList<T>

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways that you can add items to an existing collection of not known type:

Check for the `IList` interface or check of an `Add` method as a fallback;

```
public void Add(object obj, string propertyName, IEnumerable enumerable)
{
    Action<object> add;

    PropertyInfo prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    var property = prop.GetValue(obj, null);

    var collection = property as IList;

    // Check for IList
    if(collection != null)
    {
        add = item => collection.Add(item);
    }
    // Try to get an Add method as fallback
    else
    {
        var objType = obj.GetType();
        var addMethod = objType.GetMethod("Add", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        // Property doesn't support Adding
        if(addMethod == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Method Add does not exist on class " + objType.Name);

        add = item => addMethod.Invoke(obj, new object[] { item });
    }

    foreach (var item in enumerable)
    {
        add(item);
    }
}
```

I would probably go with Marc's way since it's more type safe.

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        Bar = new List<string>();
    }

    public List<string> Bar { get; set; }
    public string Qux { get; set; }
}

var result = new Foo();
var key = "Bar";

var list = new List<object> { "A", "B" };

Add(result, key, list);
```