# Dll Private method throw "not accesible due to access level" WITHIN owner class

Tags: c#, exception, dll, visual-studio-2015

I'm an amateur and not English native speaker. I'm trying to do mapper for use it with Dapper's dynamic results, I need it for a personal project and I couldn't adapt self Dapper mapper either Automapper to my needs (probably due to my lack of knowledge), so I decided to make mine.

It works flawlessly when I add the mapper code with "*Add -> Existing Item*", but if I try to use it as a DLL it throws the "not accessible due to access level" exception, pointing this part of the code:

```
    public T Map(IEnumerable<dynamic> dapperResult, bool cleanResult = false)
    {
        var parser = new PrePostFixesParser(this);
        T mapped = this.NewObject(dapperResult.First()); <------//EXCEPTION HERE
        if (_OnlyConstructor.Contains(this.TType)) return mapped;
        //... Other things
```

The method `NewObject`:

```
    private T NewObject(dynamic dyn)
    {
        Type t = typeof(T);
        bool IsInterfaceNotIEnumerable = t.IsInterface 
            && !typeof(IDictionary).IsAssignableFrom(t) 
            && !(typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(t) && !typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(t));
        if (IsInterfaceNotIEnumerable)
            throw new CustomException_DapperMapper(
                @"DapperMapper.NewObject: Exception trying to instantiate an interface that isn't an IEnumerable. This is a BUG.");

        T newObj;
        //if there are a constructor configurated
        if (_Constructors.ContainsKey(this.TType))
        {
            //object[] constructorParams = GetConstructorParams();
            try
            {
                Func<dynamic, T> constDelegate = (Func<dynamic, T>)_Constructors[this.TType];
                newObj = constDelegate(dyn);
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                throw new CustomException_DapperMapper(
                    $@"DapperMapper.NewObject: Exception using constructor to create object of type {TType.Name} with delegate {_Constructors[TType]}.", err);
            }
        }
        //if there are no constructor configurated, use parameterless constructor
        else newObj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        return newObj;
    }
```

Both methods are part of the same class called `DapperMapper`. I've read the page always want all the possible code in the same question, so I'm posting the entire class here, but it's a large one, so I'm posting too the link to [Github](https://github.com/NoxLP/DapperMapperQueryBuilder/blob/master/DapperMapperQueryBuilder/Mapper/Mapper.cs) where I have all the solution... just in case:

```
public class DapperMapper<T> : DMStatic_Mapper, iDapperMapper
{
    public DapperMapper(MapperStore store)
    {
        this.TType = typeof(T);
        this.MappersStore = store;
        this.MappersStore.StoreMapper(this.TType, this);
    }

    #region properties
    public MapperStore MappersStore { get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<MemberInfo, MemberTypeInfo> mtInfos { get { return _mtInfos[this.TType]; } }
    public Type TType { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> NamesList { get { return _NamesList[this.TType]; } }
    public Tuple<string[], bool> Prefixes { get { return _Prefixes.ContainsKey(this.TType) ? _Prefixes[this.TType] : null; } }
    public Tuple<string[], bool> Postfixes { get { return _Postfixes.ContainsKey(this.TType) ? _Postfixes[this.TType] : null; } }
    #endregion

    #region helpers
    private T NewObject(dynamic dyn)
    {
        Type t = typeof(T);
        bool IsInterfaceNotIEnumerable = t.IsInterface 
            && !typeof(IDictionary).IsAssignableFrom(t) 
            && !(typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(t) && !typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(t));
        if (IsInterfaceNotIEnumerable)
            throw new CustomException_DapperMapper(
                @"DapperMapper.NewObject: Exception trying to instantiate an interface that isn't an IEnumerable. This is a BUG.");

        T newObj;
        //if there are a constructor configurated
        if (_Constructors.ContainsKey(this.TType))
        {
            //object[] constructorParams = GetConstructorParams();
            try
            {
                Func<dynamic, T> constDelegate = (Func<dynamic, T>)_Constructors[this.TType];
                newObj = constDelegate(dyn);
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                throw new CustomException_DapperMapper(
                    $@"DapperMapper.NewObject: Exception using constructor to create object of type {TType.Name} 
with delegate {_Constructors[TType]}.", err);
            }
        }
        //if there are no constructor configurated, use parameterless constructor
        else newObj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        return newObj;
    }
    #endregion

    #region public methods
    /// <summary>
    /// Remove duplicated results due to JOINs.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="origDapperResult"></param>
    /// <param name="cleanResult"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<dynamic> GetDistinctDapperResult(IEnumerable<dynamic> origDapperResult, bool cleanResult)
    {            
        PrePostFixesParser parser = new PrePostFixesParser(this);
        IEnumerable<string> names = this.NamesList;
        List<dynamic> result = new List<dynamic>();

        foreach(dynamic dyn in origDapperResult)
        {
            IDictionary<string, object> dict = 
                (!cleanResult ? parser.GetTypeMembersWithoutPrePostFixes(dyn, names) : dyn) 
                as IDictionary<string, object>;

            bool distinct = true;
            foreach(dynamic resultDyn in result)
            {
                IDictionary<string, object> resDict = resultDyn as IDictionary<string, object>;

                if(dict.Keys.SequenceEqual(resDict.Keys) && dict.Values.SequenceEqual(resDict.Values))
                {
                    distinct = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (distinct) result.Add(dyn);
        }
        return result;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Check if the dynamic object have all the members needed to map a new T object, except those setted as IEnumerable,
    /// which should be provided in others dynamic.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dyn"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool CheckIfDynamicHasAllTypeMembersByName(dynamic dyn)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> membersDict = dyn as IDictionary<string, object>;
        IEnumerable<string> dynList = membersDict.Select(kvp => kvp.Key);
        PrePostFixesParser parser = new PrePostFixesParser(this);
        IEnumerable<string> list = parser.GetCleanNamesList(this.NamesList);

        return !dynList.Except(list).Any() && !list.Except(dynList).Any();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Check if the dynamic object have all the members needed to map a new T object, except those setted as IEnumerable,
    /// which should be provided in others dynamic.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="membersDict"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool CheckIfDynamicHasAllTypeMembersByName(IDictionary<string, object> membersDict)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> dynList = membersDict.Select(kvp => kvp.Key);
        PrePostFixesParser parser = new PrePostFixesParser(this);

        return dynList.SequenceEqual(parser.GetCleanNamesList(this.NamesList));
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Generic Map.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dapperResult"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public T Map(IEnumerable<dynamic> dapperResult, bool cleanResult = false)
    {
        var parser = new PrePostFixesParser(this);
        T mapped = this.NewObject(dapperResult.First());
        if (_OnlyConstructor.Contains(this.TType)) return mapped;

        //TODO: divide el siguiente foreach en dos con dos nuevos diccionarios estáticos, uno para pInfos y otro para fInfos, 
        //aunque se repita código: hacer métodos para cada parte del código del tipo:
        //private T PreMapCreator(KeyValuePair<PropertyInfo, MemberTypeInfo> kvp, IEnumerable<dynamic> dapperResult, bool cleanResult = false)
        //private T PreMapIEnumerable(KeyValuePair<PropertyInfo, MemberTypeInfo> kvp, IEnumerable<dynamic> dapperResult, bool cleanResult = false)
        //...

        //Loop through all members
        foreach (KeyValuePair<MemberInfo, MemberTypeInfo> kvp in mtInfos)
        {
            if (kvp.Value == MemberTypeInfo.Ignore)
                continue;
            //Member have a creator
            else if ((kvp.Value & MemberTypeInfo.Creator) == MemberTypeInfo.Creator)
            {
                //MemberDelegate mDel = (MemberDelegate)_MembersCreators[this.TType][kvp.Key.Name];
                Func<dynamic, object> mDel = (Func<dynamic, object>)_MembersCreators[this.TType][kvp.Key.Name];

                if (kvp.Key.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property) ((PropertyInfo)kvp.Key).SetValue(mapped, mDel(dapperResult));
                else ((FieldInfo)kvp.Key).SetValue(mapped, mDel(dapperResult));
            }
            //Member is IDictionary or IEnumerable
            else if ((kvp.Value & MemberTypeInfo.IEnumerable) == MemberTypeInfo.IEnumerable)
            {
                Type t = GetMemberType(kvp.Key);
                //if ((kvp.Value & MemberTypeInfo.Interface) == MemberTypeInfo.Interface) t = ResolveInterface(kvp.Key, dapperResult);
                //else t = GetMemberType(kvp.Key);
                /*
                {
                    //Type of property or field
                    if (kvp.Key.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property) t = ((PropertyInfo)kvp.Key).PropertyType;
                    else t = ((FieldInfo)kvp.Key).FieldType;
                }*/
                bool isAnInterface = (kvp.Value & MemberTypeInfo.Interface) == MemberTypeInfo.Interface;
                bool isNested = (kvp.Value & MemberTypeInfo.Nested) == MemberTypeInfo.Nested;

                //If member is a dictionary
                if (typeof(IDictionary).IsAssignableFrom(t))
                {
                    //Create a dummy dictionary with the dapper's dynamic result which should be equal to the final one
                    DictionaryMapper dictMapper = new DictionaryMapper(dapperResult, kvp.Key.Name, isNested, isAnInterface, cleanResult, t, this);

                    try
                    {
                        if (kvp.Key.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property) ((PropertyInfo)kvp.Key).SetValue(mapped, dictMapper.DummyDictionary);
                        else ((FieldInfo)kvp.Key).SetValue(mapped, dictMapper.DummyDictionary);
                    }
                    catch (Exception err)
                    {
                        throw new CustomException_DapperMapper(
                            $@"DapperMapper.Map: Couldn't map IDictionary member {kvp.Key.Name} with value contained by dynamic object.
Incorrect type of value?: {kvp.Value.ToString()}",
                            err);
                    }
                }
                //Rest of enumerables
                else
                {
                    IEnumerable<dynamic> iEnumDapperResult;
                    //Select current member's values from dynamic
                    if (isNested && !cleanResult)
                    {
                        //Type mType = t; // GetMemberType(kvp.Key);//IEnumerable<T>
                        Type genericType = t.GenericTypeArguments[0];//mType.GenericTypeArguments[0];//T
                        if ((kvp.Value & MemberTypeInfo.Interface) == MemberTypeInfo.Interface)
                        {
                            bool genericIsInterfaceNotIEnumerable =
                                genericType.IsInterface &&
                                !typeof(IDictionary).IsAssignableFrom(genericType) &&
                                !(typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(genericType) && !typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(genericType));

                            if (genericIsInterfaceNotIEnumerable) genericType = ResolveInterface(genericType, dapperResult);
                        }

                        iDapperMapper nestedMapper = MappersStore.GetMapper(genericType);
                        var nestedParser = new PrePostFixesParser(nestedMapper);

                        iEnumDapperResult = dapperResult
                            .Select(dyn => nestedParser.GetTypeMembersWithoutPrePostFixes(dyn, nestedMapper.NamesList));
                    }
                    else if (!cleanResult) iEnumDapperResult = dapperResult.Select(dyn => parser.RemovePrePostFixesFromDictionary(dyn));
                    else iEnumDapperResult = dapperResult;

                    //Create dummy IEnumerable
                    EnumerableMapper enumMapper = new EnumerableMapper(iEnumDapperResult, kvp.Key.Name, isNested, t, this.TType); ;
                    var dummy = Activator.CreateInstance(t, enumMapper.DummyEnumerable);

                    try
                    {
                        if (kvp.Key.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property) ((PropertyInfo)kvp.Key).SetValue(mapped, dummy);
                        else ((FieldInfo)kvp.Key).SetValue(mapped, dummy);
                    }
                    catch (Exception err)
                    {
                        throw new CustomException_DapperMapper(
                            $@"DapperMapper.Map: Couldn't map IEnumerable member {kvp.Key.Name} with value contained by dynamic object.
Incorrect type of value?: {kvp.Value.ToString()}",
                            err);
                    }
                }
            }//End IDictionary/IEnumerable
            //If Built-in
            else if ((kvp.Value & MemberTypeInfo.BuiltIn) == MemberTypeInfo.BuiltIn)
            {
                string name = parser.RemoveFieldsUnderscore(kvp.Key.Name);
                IDictionary<string, object> dapperDict;
                if (!cleanResult)
                    dapperDict = parser.GetTypeMembersWithoutPrePostFixes(dapperResult.First(), NamesList) as IDictionary<string, object>;
                else
                    dapperDict = dapperResult.First() as IDictionary<string, object>;

                if (!dapperDict.ContainsKey(name))
                    throw new CustomException_DapperMapper(
                        $@"DapperMapper.Map: There's no member in dynamic dapper result with name {kvp.Key.Name}. Cannot Map object.");

                try
                {
                    if (kvp.Key.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property) ((PropertyInfo)kvp.Key).SetValue(mapped, dapperDict[name]);
                    else ((FieldInfo)kvp.Key).SetValue(mapped, dapperDict[name]);
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    throw new CustomException_DapperMapper(
                        $@"DapperMapper.Map: Couldn't map BuiltIn-type member {kvp.Key.Name} with value contained by dynamic object.
Incorrect type of value?: {kvp.Value.ToString()}",
                        err);
                }
            }
            //if nested
            else if ((kvp.Value & MemberTypeInfo.Nested) == MemberTypeInfo.Nested)
            {
                Type mType = GetMemberType(kvp.Key);

                if ((kvp.Value & MemberTypeInfo.Interface) == MemberTypeInfo.Interface)
                    mType = ResolveInterface(mType, dapperResult);

                //access generic Map method through nongeneric interface method
                iDapperMapper nestedMapper = MappersStore.GetMapper(mType);

                if (nestedMapper == null)
                    throw new CustomException_DapperMapper(
                        $@"DapperMapper.Map: No Mapper found at store for property {kvp.Key.Name} of type {mType.ToString()}.
If you want to map a nested property you have to create a mapper for that property type.");

                if (kvp.Key.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
                    ((PropertyInfo)kvp.Key).SetValue(mapped, nestedMapper.NoGenericMap(dapperResult, cleanResult));
                else ((FieldInfo)kvp.Key).SetValue(mapped, nestedMapper.NoGenericMap(dapperResult, cleanResult));
            }
        }

        return mapped;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Generic map to IEnumerables. Result HAVE to be ordered by the splitOn column.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="R"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="dapperResult"></param>
    /// <param name="splitOn"></param>
    /// <param name="cleanResult"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public R Map<R>(IEnumerable<dynamic> dapperResult, string splitOn = "Id", bool cleanResult = false)
        where R : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        R result;
        Type r = typeof(R);
        List<dynamic> singleObjectDynamic = new List<dynamic>();
        object splitObject = (dapperResult.First() as IDictionary<string, object>)[splitOn];

        if (typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(r))
        {
            result = (R)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(this.TType));

            foreach (dynamic dyn in dapperResult)
            {
                IDictionary<string, object> dict = dyn as IDictionary<string, object>;
                if (!dict.ContainsKey(splitOn))
                    throw new CustomException_DapperMapper(
                        $@"DapperMapper.Map(IEnumerable): Dapper result doesn't have a member with name equals to splitOn parameter.
SplitOn = {splitOn}");

                if (!object.Equals(splitObject, dict[splitOn]) || dapperResult.Last() == dyn)
                {
                    ((IList)result).Add(Map(singleObjectDynamic));
                    singleObjectDynamic.Clear();
                    splitObject = dict[splitOn];
                }
                else
                    singleObjectDynamic.Add(dyn);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251587/assign-any-ienumerable-to-object-property
            var addMethod = r.GetMethod("Add", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

            // Property doesn't support Adding
            if (addMethod == null)
                throw new CustomException_DapperMapper(
                    $@"DapperMapper.Map(IEnumerable): Method Add doesn't exist in enumerable type to map.
enumType: {r.Name}.");

            if (r.IsGenericTypeDefinition) result = (R)Activator.CreateInstance(r.MakeGenericType(this.TType));
            else result = (R)Activator.CreateInstance(r);

            foreach (dynamic dyn in dapperResult)
            {
                IDictionary<string, object> dict = dyn as IDictionary<string, object>;
                if (!dict.ContainsKey(splitOn))
                    throw new CustomException_DapperMapper(
                        $@"DapperMapper.Map(IEnumerable): Dapper result doesn't have a member with name equals to splitOn parameter.
SplitOn = {splitOn}");

                if (!object.Equals(splitObject, dict[splitOn]) || dapperResult.Last() == dyn)
                {
                    addMethod.Invoke(result, new object[] { NoGenericMap(dyn) });
                    singleObjectDynamic.Clear();
                    splitObject = dict[splitOn];
                }
                else
                    singleObjectDynamic.Add(dyn);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Non-generic Map.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dapperResult"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public object NoGenericMap(dynamic dapperResult, bool cleanResult = false)
    {
        IEnumerable<dynamic> ienum = new List<dynamic>() { dapperResult } as IEnumerable<dynamic>;
        return this.Map(ienum, cleanResult);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Non-generic Map.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dapperResult"></param>
    /// <param name="cleanResult"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public object NoGenericMap(IEnumerable<dynamic> dapperResult, bool cleanResult = false)
    {
        return this.Map(dapperResult, cleanResult);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

## **QUESTION**

So, **what's happening**?

I'm astonished by this one. Am I **terribly** wrong or class's methods should be able to see same class `private` methods?

For the DLL I just began it with a new Class Library project in visual studio 2015 community, and when done build it with the typical release configuration, then I went to a console project I'm using to testing it (I just made a simple database there, to have direct Dapper's dynamic results objects to test it) and added reference to the DLL. Could it be that I build the DLL wrong? Do I have to do something more in the testing project apart from referencing the DLL and add the corresponding `using namespace`?

I've tried searching for private methods, DLLs, private methods in DLLs, private methods in the public class in DLLs, but it seems I'm not able to find anything that solves it. Apart from checking the class and method have the proper access keywords (c# default access is private if no other is specified, right?), and clean, build, rebuild again both solutions, I don't see anymore.

I'm afraid I'm just forgetting something stupid, but it works if I copy-paste the code (or add it with "*Add->Existing Item*" as I said before") instead of using the DLL, therefore the code is correct, right?

**EDIT:**
Due to comment of GSerg I'm adding the way I call `DapperMapper` in the testing project after adding the reference to the DLL:

```
MapperStore store = new MapperStore();
DapperMapper<Persons> mapper = (DapperMapper<Persons>)store.GetMapper(typeof(Persons));
Persons p = mapper.Map(result);
```

**EDIT2:**
As can be seen in the comments, as suggested by GSerg I created a new console project for testing, add the reference to the DLL, copy-paste ONLY the test (mock classes, database), hit F5 and got the same result. I double checked that I builded the DLL and the test project at release mode, and use windows explorer to confirm that there were no DLL's .cs files at the testing project.

Comment: So you add the dll as a reference, create an instance of `DapperMapper<T>`, call `Map()` on it, and at that point VS goes to the source code of the library you've added and highlights `T mapped = this.NewObject(dapperResult.First());` inside the `Map()` method as an error?

Comment: Yes, should I add that proccess to the question? Done.

Comment: Does the same happen when you don't have the DLL source code in your solution and only reference the release dll?

Comment: @GSerg Yes, that's when the exception is threw.

Comment: Then it would not go to the source code and would have nothing to highlight. If it still highlights, you are not doing what you're saying you're doing.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but it happens as I said :( Before referencing the DLL I had the code pasted directly into the testing project, a few days ago I remove it, could it be that?

Comment: Please create a new testing project and reference the dll from it.

Comment: @GSerg Ok, as you suggested I've just created a new console project, add the reference to the DLL, copy-paste ONLY the test (mock classes and database), and hit F5. Again same exception and again the exception points to that method, even when the .cs itself never was on the project, and I have confirmed manually with the explorer that the project folder doesn't have the file inside, vstudio just open the file and points to the method. Does vstudio have the ability to just open .cs files of referenced DLLs? F.i. if I have the files in my computer in other folder?

Comment: Did you build the library in the release mode and reference the release build?

Comment: Yes, I've double checked (and clean-rebuild) that I used the release mode in the DLL project, I've even tried referencing each DLL in original library project "bin" and "obj" folders.